# Where clause doesn't work

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get data from two tables. Here is my code:

```
select p.nim, p.title, s.name, p.year, substring(p.abstrak, 1, 100), p.path, p.status 
from student s 
join project p 
on s.nim = p.nim
where p.title like "%foot%" 
or p.title like "%ball%" and p.status = 'active'
```

The idea is not getting data with inactive status. But this query keeps returning data with inactive status.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @marc_s thank you.. that make me understand what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
    p.nim, p.title, s.name, p.year, substring(p.abstrak, 1, 100), 
    p.path, p.status 
from student s 
join project p on s.nim = p.nim 
where 
    (p.title like "%foot%" or p.title like "%ball%") and p.status = 'active'
```

It's the same concept as [Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) in math:

```
1 + 2 * 3 = 7

1 + (2 * 3) = 7

(1 + 2) * 3 = 9
```

Comment: No, that's _your_ responsibility, Yogev :-) You're supposed to provide the solution _and_ explanations as to why that solutions is correct and the original was incorrect. That will make your answers _so_ much better (and probably get an upvote from me).

Comment: @marc_s had a great explanation in a comment just above me (for some reason I can't see it anymore...) and I didn't want to steal his thunder ;)

Comment: @godmoney yeah, marc_s has a great explanation(me too can't see it any more..) big thanks for both of you..^^

Comment: @godmoney: you basically summed it up just as nicely as I did! :-) Just wrap the conditions joined by `OR` in a set of parenthesis, since otherwise, the `AND` will take precedence and the condition is interpreted in a "wrong" way

Comment: I think the "Order of operations" was an addition by JohnB